# How to make zsh vi-style commands respect WORDCHARS?

Tags: command-line, zsh

I prefer `vi-style` word movements such as `vi-forward-word` instead of `forward-word`, so that the cursor also stops on separator characters. However, I would also like to make `zsh` respect `WORDCHARS` in this case or somehow define my separator characters. Is this possible somehow? It seems I can either make `zsh` use my separator characters, or use `vi-style` movements where it also stops on them, but not both.

So e.g. if my line is the following:

```
% ls -la /foo/bar/f-b/r
```

then if I start moving forward word by word, it will stop on `/`, `foo`, `/`, `bar`, `/`, `f-b`, `/`, `r`.

Relevant lines from my `.zshrc`:

```
WORDCHARS='*?_-.[]~=&;!#$%^(){}<>'  # removed /

autoload select-word-style                                                                                                                             
select-word-style normal

bindkey '^W'     vi-backward-kill-word
bindkey '^f'     vi-forward-word
bindkey '^b'     vi-backward-word
```

Comment: I know `zsh` well enough to suggest that you can write a custom `zle` widget to give you the behavior you want, but not well enough to suggest how to go about writing it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - that's what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I just implemented my own `zle` widgets:

```
SEPCHARS='[/ ]'

my-forward-word() {
    if [[ "${BUFFER[CURSOR + 1]}" =~ "${SEPCHARS}" ]]; then
        (( CURSOR += 1 ))
        return
    fi
    while [[ CURSOR -lt "${#BUFFER}" && ! "${BUFFER[CURSOR + 1]}" =~ "${SEPCHARS}" ]]; do
        (( CURSOR += 1 ))
    done
}

zle -N my-forward-word
bindkey '^f' my-forward-word

my-backward-word() {
    if [[ "${BUFFER[CURSOR]}" =~ "${SEPCHARS}" ]]; then
        (( CURSOR -= 1 ))
        return
    fi
    while [[ CURSOR -gt 0 && ! "${BUFFER[CURSOR]}" =~ "${SEPCHARS}" ]]; do
        (( CURSOR -= 1 ))
    done
}

zle -N my-backward-word
bindkey '^b' my-backward-word

my-backward-kill-word() {
    if [[ "${LBUFFER[CURSOR]}" =~ "${SEPCHARS}" ]]; then
        LBUFFER="${LBUFFER[1, CURSOR - 1]}"
        return
    fi
    while [[ CURSOR -gt 0 && ! "${LBUFFER[CURSOR]}" =~ "${SEPCHARS}" ]]; do
            LBUFFER="${LBUFFER[1, CURSOR - 1]}"
    done
}

zle -N my-backward-kill-word
bindkey '^W' my-backward-kill-word
```